# what should a controller action look like if it just redirects?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a action that just does some db work based on the parameter passed into it, then it redirects to another page.

What should the return type be then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RedirectToRouteResult` for redirecting to same controller's action :

```
public RedirectToRouteResult DeleteAction(long itemId)
{
    // Do stuff
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Or use this to redirect to another controller's action :

```
public RedirectToRouteResult DeleteAction(long itemId)
{
    // Do stuff
    return 
      new RedirectToRouteResult(
         new RouteValueDictionary(
          new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", Id = itemId})
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it alway redirects, the return type might as well be **RedirectToRouteResult** or **RedirectResult**, depending on whether you are redirecting to an action or a URL.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021568/must-asp-net-mvc-controller-methods-return-actionresult) for a similar discussion.

Here's an example:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult Foo()
{
    return this.RedirectToAction("Bar");
}
```