# Problems with RedirectToAction MVC2 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, redirecttoaction

I am receiving this error when trying to use RedirectToAction, can anyone offer any advice on why this could be occuring, ive used this before without any problems, i must be missing something.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult'

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Edit(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            customersRepository.SaveCustomer(customer);
            TempData["message"] = customer.CustomerName + " has been saved.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        else //validation error, so redisplay the same view
            return View(customer);

    }
```

Regards

Liam

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try changing `public ViewResult Edit(Customer customer)` to `public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer)`

ViewResult is derived from ActionResult and can only return Views. Since your code can return a View or a Redirect, you should use an ActionResult. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4743756/106866) for more information.

Comment: thanks for that i thought it would likely to be something simple.

Comment: I updated my answer. basically, a `ViewResult` can only return a `View`, not a `RedirectToAction`