# cannot convert expression type error in ReturnToAction when calling an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

While returning an action instead of returning a view in MVC applicationI am getting 
Error:  **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult'**

For example:

```
public ViewResult Today()
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now;
            return View("DateTimeView", date);
        }
public ViewResult Test()
        {
            return **RedirectToAction("Today");**
        }
```

I am getting 
Error:  **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult'**

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226811/problems-with-redirecttoaction-mvc2-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226811/problems-with-redirecttoaction-mvc2-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-web)

Comment: The reason it needs to be `ActionResult` is that `ActionResult` is the base class for all the various results you can return from controller actions (hence the name). `ViewResult` is a very specific return type for returning Views only so cannot be cast to from a `RedirectToRouteResult` which is what `RedirectToAction` returns. The default MVC scaffolding for controllers always defaults to `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the return type of your action to **ActionResult** instead of **ViewResult**.
You can do like this:

```
public ActionResult Today()
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now;
            return View("DateTimeView", date);
        }
public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Today");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan but could you tell me why it was not working with ViewResult? Because i have a piece of code in which it is working for ViewResult also.

Comment: @sankalp ActionResult is a return type compatible with both ViewResult and RedirectToRouteResult, while for ViewResult its not the case