# ViewResult V/S ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to decide whether to use ActionResult or ViewResult? I know that ActionResult is an abstract class with ViewResult as a subtype but I have seen examples using both of these for the same functionality. Is there something that differentiates between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference Between ViewResult() and ActionResult()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743741/difference-between-viewresult-and-actionresult)

Comment: Hi, new to programming here, why constrict, why not just use actionresult instead of viewresult? is  it just a security reason, program leakage reason?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`ActionResult` is base type while `ViewResult` is subtype of `ActionResult`.

When you set Action's return type `ActionResult`, you can return any subtype of it e.g **Json,PartialView,View,RedirectToAction**.

But when you use subtype as in this case `ViewResult` you are bounding your action that it will only return subtype as result which in this case is **View**.

When you use `ActionResult` as return type, you can return the following from Action(which means following are the subtypes of **ActionResult**), as explained on **forums.asp.net**:

> > **ActionResult** is a general result type that can have several subtypes (from **"ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Quickly"** Book):
> >
> > a) **ViewResult**
> >
> > Renders a specifed view to the response stream
> >
> > b) **PartialViewResult**
> >
> > Renders a specifed partial view to the response stream
> >
> > c) **EmptyResult**
> >
> > Basically does nothing; an empty response is given
> >
> > d) **RedirectResult**
> >
> > Performs an HTTP redirection to a specifed URL
> >
> > e) **RedirectToRouteResult**
> >
> > Performs an HTTP redirection to a URL that is determined  by the routing engine, based on given route data
> >
> > f) **JsonResult**
> >
> > Serializes a given ViewData object to JSON format
> >
> > g) **JavaScriptResult**
> >
> > Returns a piece of JavaScript code that can be executed on
> >     the client
> >
> > h) **ContentResult**
> >
> > Writes content to the response stream without requiring  a view
> >
> > i) **FileContentResult**
> >
> > Returns a fle to the client
> >
> > j) **FileStreamResult**
> >
> > Returns a fle to the client, which is provided by a Stream
> >
> > k) **FilePathResult**
> >
> > Returns a fle to the client

## When to Use ViewResult

if you are sure that your action method will return some **view page**, you can use **ViewResult**. But if your action method may have different behavior, like either render a view or perform a redirection. You can use the more general base class **ActionResult** as the return type.

For more details:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1448398.aspx

Also you can refer here:

http://www.slideshare.net/umarali1981/difference-between-action-result-and-viewresult

Comment: Didn't realize there were so many return types ! Jazakallah,
As of now in asp.net mvc 5, the more complete list goes here in [MSDN - ActionResult Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Hi, new to programming here, why constrict, why not just use actionresult instead of viewresult? is  it just a security reason, program leakage reason?

Comment: there is no harm in using `ActionResult` too, you can

Answer (score 0):

If you use View result you have to return a view like

```
public ViewResult MyView ()
{
   return View();
}
```

If you mark it to Action result you can return variety of result like

```
public ActionResult MyView ()
{
   //can return view
   //can return partial view
   //can return json
   //can return javascript
   // redirect to another action
   // and many more  :)
}
```

And as the basic of OOPS that always code for abstraction rather then concrete ActionResult is always a plus to use.

For more information on ActionResult please follow the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First to Understand---ActionResult and ViewResult are basically a return type for an method(i.e Action in MVC).

Second The Difference is --- ActionResult can return any type of Result Whereas ViewResult can return result type of 
View Only.

Comment: Difference between ActionResult VS ViewResult