# What are the return types of MVC actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view

What are the possible types of return type for MVC4 actions ?

I do aware for following:
                               FileResult, JSONResult, ActionResult

do we have any other option to return from controller's action ?

Comment: As an aside to @Saranga's answer, if one is working with WebAPI, consider returning IHttpActionResult. Since it's an interface, it makes for easy unit testing.

Comment: refer my answer hope it helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604106/viewresult-v-s-actionresult/24604146#24604146

Answer (score 2):

ViewResult, PartialViewResult, RedirectResult and more.

Check [ActionResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd493064(v=vs.118)).

Thanks!