# How to change the return type dynamically for the MVC.NET controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a function that is supposed to return the view results to print the output. The complexity though that based on a condition I have to change the report type. I either have to return the FileContentResult or the ViewResult. Is there an efficient way to change the output type dynamically when returning the value from the controller method in MVC application?

Thank you very much in advance!

```
public ViewResult PrintReport(int reportId)
{

    if (UseStream())
    {
        return return File(GetReportBytes(), @"application/pdf");
    }
    else
    {
        SetBaseViewModel(printResultViewModel, "Report Title");
        return View("PrintReport", printResultViewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `ActionResult`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604106/viewresult-v-s-actionresult

Comment: Both `ViewResult` and `FileResult` have a shared parent class: `ActionResult`. Changing your return type to that would allow this code to compile.

Comment: Thank you very much, the ActionResult does resolve the issue